# Using C++ DLLs in Python

Tags: python, c++, dll, swig, boost-python

I'm sorry if the question seems repeated many times here but I spent the whole day without finding a clear answer.

I'm working under Visual Studio 2010 and i'm trying to load a class defined in a DLL into Python. I saw that there's no way to do this without making a C++ wrapper (using eventually SWIG or Boost.Python). I'm not a C++ programmer and I couldn't find an easy and clear tutorial to start with, I will be grateful if you could give me a simple one.

Also, my class uses the singleton pattern that restricts its instantiation to one object like this :

```
MyClass*    MyClass::getInstance()
{
    if(instance==NULL)                  
        instance    =   new MyClass();      

    return instance;
}
```

So I need to know how I can deal with this in my Python script so that I can create an instance of MyClass and access all its methods.

Thanks guys.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html

Comment: You've told us almost nothing about your scenario other than the one comment about singletons. What exactly are you struggling with that isn't already described much better than I could in http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGPlus.html ?

Comment: Actually that part about singletons that I posted is what I need the most. I don't know how to handle pointers in Python. For example, I'd do something like :
    _import MyDLL_
    _instance = MyDLL.getInstance()_
    _instance.someMethod()_

But I'm not sure it will be that simple..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the solution to my problem, I come back to answer my question to whom it might help.

I used SWIG to make the C++ wrapper. So I defined the module interface something like :

```
%module MyClass
    %{
    #include    "MyClass.h"
    %}
    %include <windows.i>   //if you're using __declspec(dllexport) to export dll
    %include "MyClass.h"
```

Then compiled it directly with :

```
    >swig -c++ -python MyClass.i
```

And that generates two files : *MyClass.py* and *MyClass_wrap.cxx*.

I then included the MyClass_wrap.cxx file to my project in Visual Studio and made these changes on my project properties :

Configuration properties > General > Target Name : **_MyClass**
Target Extension : **.pyd**

C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories : **/path/to/Python/include**

Linker > Additional Library Directories : **//path/to/Python/libs**

And then compiled the project to generate *_MyClass.pyd*.

In my Python script, it is as simple as the following :

```
import MyClass
instance = MyClass.MyClass.getInstance()
#and then use all MyClass methods via instance, ex: instance.SomeMethod()
```

That's all. SWIG does all the work to handle the reference returned by getInstance().